# How to associate a getter/setter with a sml structure

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am relatively new to SML (coming from java world) and from what I understand 
structures are similar to java classes & signatures are java interfaces.

Everything in SML structure is immutable. Is there any possibility to have a variable whose value can be set ?

```
functor Make(M : sig
                 type data
                 val callback : _
             end) = struct

    val cb  = M.callback

    fun simple nn =
        cb(nn);
        return nn

    fun changeCallback cc = 
        cb = cc
end
```

The above code compiles fine without changeCallback function. Is there any way to change the value of variable cb and give a different callback function ?

Answer (score 2):

Structures are most similar Java classes which cannot be instantiated and which have only static members.  Like in Java, having global mutable state is considered a bad idea.

You can add mutable global state with a

```
val cb : (argtype -> unit) ref = ref M.callback
```

declaration, just as you could have a `public static Callback` member in a Java class.  But this tends to cause problems.  You would also have to adjust the rest of the code a bit, to read the reference with `!` and write to it using `:=`:

```
functor Make(M : sig
                 type data
                 type arg
                 val callback : arg -> unit
             end) = struct

    val cb = ref M.callback

    fun simple nn = ((!cb) nn; nn)

    fun changeCallback cc =
        cb := cc
end
```

Also note that there is no `new` operator for SML structures.  Functors can be used to create new structures, but all of them have to be represented at the source level.  For example, it is not possible to create a variable number of structures in a loop.

To emulate Java class, you need to use records (possibly with members with `… ref` types).

Comment: So now I can set `state` within changeCallback() ? But then I have a function reference not really a int. What would be the syntax for that (already tried `_`) ?

Comment: I don't recognize the `_` syntax. I think you need to supply a concrete type in the functor's signature argument.

Answer (score 1):

To supply Florian's answer, SML does have mutable variables where `val foo = ref 0` makes `foo` a mutable int, `!foo` is the dereferenced value (the actual int), `foo := 2` changes its value, and `fun incr r = (r := !r + 1 ; !r)` is a function that increments its mutable argument by 1 and returns the updated value. This is done without the use of the module system (structures, signatures, functors). Note that it is better to think of `;` as a binary operator in SML than a "statement separator" as it would be seen in an imperative language.

SML doesn't have support for class-based object-oriented programming like Ocaml does, and frankly it would be a pity to simulate this with the module system. You may want to look into [Ocaml's object-oriented programming](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/objects.html).

If you're trying to accomplish a specific task where your class-based thinking is in the way, perhaps a better question to ask is "How would you model X in SML?", considering it isn't object-oriented.